# Can we have a background vpn application( without active notification)?

Tags: android, vpn

I want to develop a VPN application without active notification. For developing VPN applications in android, I should create a service extending `VpnService` and other apps bind to it. Is `VpnService` a foreground service or background?. Foreground service is a type of service that has an active notification. But I don't want active notification and I want my VPN app to be without notification in the tray. Is this possible? Is there a good example source code?

Comment: to run **any** service in background without OS killing it, you need a foreground service. There are no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can run background service without notification on try but it will be destroy after 2 minutes for running service you have to add notification or if not you can restart service after 2 minutes when it destroy with a broadcast receiver

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service EXIT", "ondestroy!");
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
              BroadcastReceiver.class);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }
```